# Desaturating rectangle in SVG

Tags: svg, svg-filters

Suppose that I have an existing SVG scene. I would now like to paint a rectangle on top of this scene, and for all background pixels that are covered by this rectangle, I would like to apply some filter, e.g. desaturation. Note that I can do darkening/lightening using opacity, but in this case, I'd like a more complicated effect. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, use an [feColorMatrix filter](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters.html#feColorMatrixElement) type="saturate" [See here](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/images/filters/feColorMatrix.svg)

Comment: My understanding (and my testing) indicates that the filter only applies to descendants of the block you apply the filter to, not background elements. The example you've posted certainly only takes advantage of this.

Comment: @EdwardZ.Yang well, you could for example apply the filter to the root svg element (or on a <g> that contains all the background elements), and use filter subregions to only filter the rectangle you want (use x,y,width,height attributes on the feColorMatrix element) - more reading and an example here: http://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects/#FilterPrimitiveSubRegion

Comment: @Erik is it possible to put another svg pane on top of the previous one with CSS positioning and use in=BackgroundImage? It's not clear to me from the spec what the definition of the "canvas" is for an SVG element

Comment: @MichaelMullany no, becuase doing that kind of positioning would require separate svg fragments, and the 'BackgroundImage' filter input is defined as being only inside on such fragment. Also, webkit and mozilla don't implement 'BackgroundImage' AFAIK. The canvas for an SVG element is the area where svg content can be drawn (typically this area is what CSS width/height says, or the width/height attributes on the svg root in question).